# What is the difference between .m4s and .ts media files?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, mp4, hls, mpeg-dash

From my understanding they can both contain media segments and are meant to be reconstructed at the client but what is the difference between the two?

Edit: This is in the context of HLS

Comment: Have you done any research prior to asking here? Please show your effort and results.

Comment: Nothing shows up with a search, if you can find an article or page with the answer, please link it.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=.ts+file+format&t=newext&atb=v248-1&ia=web  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=.ms4+file+format&t=newext&atb=v248-1&ia=web  https://duckduckgo.com/?q=.mp4+file+format&t=newext&atb=v248-1&ia=web

Comment: Whats the difference in terms of WHAT? For the person consuming the video? Nothing is different. 

Are you asking about the file format structures? Are in interested in learning about Parameters Sets and IDRs, and network frame sizes, and Programs Reference Clocks, and AVC Annex B and ADTS headers, and about 1000 other things?. Then you need to start reading spec sheets. I recommend starting with the wikipedia article for each format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69290305/15697799

Comment: Constant virtue-signaling and condescension with no real, useful answer whatsoever. Typical StackOverflow/StackExchange.